# Is this grammatically and sensibly correct Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

I am putting together a Memorial Service Program and would like to use the Latin of:

> To love the memory of him who is so loved that it will never be forgotten and who will always be alive in our hearts.

I have tried at least three translation web tools with different back-translations plus a few people who are rusty in Latin, to translate and back-translate and I came up with the following:

> Amare memoriam eius qui sic amatur, ut numquam oblivione deleatur, quis erit semper vivara in cordibus nostris.

However, I would prefer more assurance that the Latin is grammatically and sensibly correct.

Comment: "To love the memory ..." isn't really a complete sentence. What is the context here? E.g. "We are gathered here *to love*" or "It is not hard *to love*" etc., these would result in different Latin renderings. Generally, the part before *quis* is grammatically sound, the rest not.

Comment: As I tried different English expressions like "In loving memory of...", the back-translation "To love the memory of him" seemed the most profound. It is the special, individual memory of his relationship with each person attending the memorial service that will never be forgotten. Can you suggest a different phrase?

Comment: To love the memory of the one who is so loved that it may never be forgotten, and who will live forever in our hearts.

Comment: Would this be more acceptable: "amabimus eum habentes memoriam eius qui  amatur profunde ut memoria eius deleatur,  numquam oblivione sit sed semper in cordibus nostrils vivet"